# Why is API rejecting my JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I can add an object to an API via JSON when I send the request using byte char[] however it doesn't work when I convert an NSDictionary to NSData and send that. What's the problem here ?

Here's when it works.

```
// Request

NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SOME URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.timeoutInterval = 30.000000;

// Headers

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// Body

const char bytes[98] = "{\n\t\"user\" :\n\t{\n\t\t\"email\" : \"test@gmail.com\",\n\t\t\"username\" : \"example\",\n\t\t\"password\" : \"cryptx\"\n\t}\n}";
request.HTTPBody = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:98];

// Connection

NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
[connection start];
```

This is when it doesn't work:

```
    - (void)addUser:(User *)user
{
    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"API_URL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.timeoutInterval = 30.000000;
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSData *data = [self createJSONWithUsername:@"X" andEmail:@"x@X.com" andPassword:@"pass"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (NSData *)createJSONWithUsername:(NSString *)username andEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:password, email, username, nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"password", @"email", @"username", nil];
    NSDictionary *userDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    NSDictionary *userDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userDataDictionary, @"user", nil];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    return jsonData;
}
```

The second one does not add the user while the second one does.

EDIT

JSON BEING SENT i.e. the jsonString variable

```
{
  "user" : {
    "email" : "x@X.com",
    "username" : "X",
    "password" : "pass"
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that that `const char byte[96]` is **98** characters long... I don't do Objective-C so I have no idea if that's an issue. (It's in the "this works" case anyway.)

Comment: Maybe you should actually dump the JSON you're generating and show it to us.

Comment: Indeed, the starting point is **always** to look at the actual data being sent and rejected. The only example JSON in the question is in the "this works" case, which isn't all that useful.

Comment: @HotLicks - JSON coming up..

Comment: Btw: Why are you generating an `NSData` object (`jsonData`) converting it into `NSString` (`jsonString`) and converting it back into `NSData` (`data`)?

Comment: @lootsch - it was somewhere online. Anyway, will it even matter ?

Comment: @Objective-J it shouldn't

Comment: Your JSON being sent is missing the closing `}`. Is that the complete example?

Comment: @Joe fixed it. Added the }

Comment: you definitely don't need the bit where you convert the data to a string then back. Just get the data from the dictionary and send that data.

Comment: You should specify the address of an `error*` pointer for the NSJSONSerialization operation, then after the operation check the result for nil and if nil dump the error value.

Comment: Yep, pass NSData back from your subroutine, not NSString.

Comment: (Your "JSON being sent" above is valid JSON.  Of course, it may not be what the other end expects.)

Comment: (And note that if your JSON is being rejected, the other end is likely supplying some sort of semi-meaningful error message.)

Comment: That's the problem. Its accepting it with 200 OK code. But its just not added to the database.

Comment: Fixed it the simple way. Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. It's pretty much exactly what I use in a few apps. I formatted around your provided code...

```
- (void)addUser:(NSDictionary *)sentuserdetails {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SOME URL"];
  NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
  request.timeoutInterval = 30.000000;
  [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sentuserdetails      options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]; //don't set error to nil, handle the error
  [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
  NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request           delegate:self];
  [connection start];
}
```